# If I'm trying to predict a label for a sample, but the sample is missing features, how should I deal with it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I'm having a conceptual issue right now; I know that sklearn does not like it when .predict() is used on examples with NaN values, but what should I do if I want to predict a label for a example with NaN/missing features?

Currently, I'm replacing the NaN cells with -999 as a placeholder measure, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Unfortunately, searching about missing values in prediction samples doesn't yield helpful results.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could try is to fill in the missing value in your test example with the value you use to fill in missing values in your training dataset. For example, if you fill in missing values for that feature with the mean of the training data, you could use that mean to fill in the missing value in your test example.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning models perform better when your data is complete, therefore it is advisable that you impute missing values with a summary statistic or with the same information as a closely located data point (using [KNN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer), for instance).

Scikit Learn contains a [suite of algorithms to impute missing values](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute). The most common method is to use the [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer) with a "mean" strategy.

You can also use simpler approaches and use Pandas to either fill all NAs in your dataset with [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or remove the NAs with [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

It is important that you familiarize yourself with the data that you are working with. Sometimes missing data has a meaning to it. For instance, when working with income data, some very affluent people have refused to disclose their income, whereas people with low income would always disclose it. In this case, if the income of the former group was replaced with 0 or the mean, the results of the prediction could have been invalid.

Have a look at this step-by-step guide on [how to handle missing data in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/).